# MDI Application minimize/restore issue

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi

Ok, so I have a VB .Net MDI Forms Application.

frmMain is the "parent" form with IsMDIContainer set to TRUE.

I load "frmChild" from frmMain setting the MDIparent property to frmMain.

I minimize the form, then minimize the application.
I restore the application a few minutes later, then restore frmChild and find that frmChild is now totally blank...?

This happens intermittently when I minimize the child form, then minimize the application and subsequently restore the application then restore the child form...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you want to try and alleviate the problem you can try invalidating 'frmChild' which will force it and all it's contained controls to be redrawn.